# React Bootstrap Custom CSS not remaining active on page

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

Sorry that title doesn't make a lot of sense, not sure how to word it correctly. Basically I have a css rule defined as follows:

```
.pagination>li>a:focus,
.pagination>li>a:active,
.pagination>li>span:focus,
.pagination>li>span:active {
    outline: 5px auto #711313 !important;
    outline-offset: -2px !important;
    border: 2px solid #711313 !important;
}
```

However, the outline-offset rule is not remaining constant. When the page loads, the outline is present but when I click any other pagination button the outline disappears and does not reappear UNLESS I activate a dropdown button (only dropdown buttons, no other button has this behavior) at which time the outline appears only on the current active pagination button and as soon as I click any other pagination button it disappears.

I have very similar styling on all buttons on my page and the outline-offset rule is constant for them, but for some reason my pagination buttons are losing their outline or at least the offset rule. My dev tools don't show any change in rules, but it shouldn't be being overwritten anyway because of the important flag. I'm pretty convinced this is a bug with react bootstrap but I thought I'd ask here first in case I'm missing something obvious.

edit: here are is the rendered HTML (might be some slight formatting errors)

```
<div id="pagebottom" style="float: left; clear: both;">
</div>
<div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="center btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Showing Records 150 - 175</button>
    <div class="dropup btn-group">
        <button id="resultsPerPage" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">25 Results Per Page
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="resultsPerPage">
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">10</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">25</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">50</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">100</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="">
            <a role="button" href="#" style=""><span aria-label="First">«</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">5</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">6</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a role="button" href="#">7</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">8</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">9</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">10</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#">11</a></li>
        <li class=""><a role="button" href="#"><span aria-label="Last">»</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Move to Top</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer for now since it is no longer relevant.  Ideally, if you can post the rendered elements that would be best.

Comment: I added the html, the specific item in question is the ul at the bottom